# Crashplan 4.5 On Synology Diskstation UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: linux, java, nas, synology, crashplan

I've been running [Patters' port](http://pcloadletter.co.uk/2012/01/30/crashplan-syno-package/) of [CrashPlan](https://www.code42.com/crashplan/) on my Synology Diskstation DS213j (ARM CPU). I recently upgraded the DiskStation OS to DSM 6.0.

As part of the upgrade the CrashPlan service upgraded itself to the latest version during the restart. I had a little trouble restarting CrashPlan, because this version comes with its own non-ARM JRE, so I pointed it to the Java 8 JRE which comes with DSM 6.0.

Now CrashPlan starts OK, but doesn't back up. The GUI says 'Initial backup not complete'. In the logs I see

```
ERROR 95988_AUTH-1 .service.backup.BackupController] Exception setting up BackupController! , java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /volume1/@tmp/jna-3506402/jna7016685188129052391.tmp: /volume1/@tmp/jna-3506402/jna7016685188129052391.tmp: internal error
STACKTRACE:: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /volume1/@tmp/jna-3506402/jna7016685188129052391.tmp: /volume1/@tmp/jna-3506402/jna7016685188129052391.tmp: internal error
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at com.code42.jna.LinuxPlatform.<init>(LinuxPlatform.java:76)
    at com.code42.jna.PlatformFactory.getLinuxPlatform(PlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.code42.jna.inotify.InotifyManager.<clinit>(InotifyManager.java:47)
    at com.code42.jna.inotify.JNAInotifyFileWatcherDriver.<init>(JNAInotifyFileWatcherDriver.java:22)
    at com.code42.backup.path.BackupSetsManager.initFileWatcherDriver(BackupSetsManager.java:417)
    at com.code42.backup.path.BackupSetsManager.setUp(BackupSetsManager.java:153)
    at com.code42.backup.BackupManager.setUp(BackupManager.java:141)
    at com.backup42.service.backup.BackupController.setUp(BackupController.java:456)
    at com.backup42.service.CPService.changeLicense(CPService.java:2809)
    at com.backup42.service.CPService.authorize(CPService.java:2705)
    at com.backup42.service.peer.Authorizer.doWork(Authorizer.java:927)
    at com.code42.utils.AWorker.run(AWorker.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`/volume1/@tmp/jna-3506402/jna7016685188129052391.tmp` is an ELF binary, and the directory is inside the CrashPlan JVM's tmpdir.

I am interpreting this as the new CrashPlan version ships with some native libraries, and these are not built for ARM CPUs. I also see CrashPlan 4.5 [requires Linux kernel 2.6.32 or greater](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Linux_CrashPlan_App_Version_4.5_Cannot_Back_Up), and if not present there can be problems with `inotify` calls. These are seen in the stack above.

Am I stuffed? Without the CrashPlan native libraries for my platform I don't see a way to start it. I have two years of CrashPlan subscription left, and running it from my PC is nowhere near as good as running it from my NAS for multiple reasons.

Comment: Synology kernel version (/proc/version): Linux version 3.2.40 (root@build3) (gcc version 4.9.3 20150311 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) )

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the CrashPlan-provided jna.jar with a fresh one downloaded from Maven does the trick.
See [Martin Kleinman](http://chrisnelson.ca/2015/07/02/fixing-crashplan-4-3-0-on-synology/comment-page-1/#comment-19061)'s instructions:

> 10. Download: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.2.2/jna-4.2.2.jar
> 11. go to `/var/packages/CrashPlan/target/bin` and make a backup from jna.jar ( `mv jna.jar jna.backup` )
> 12. rename the downloaded jna-4.2.2.jar to jna.jar 13 copy the jna.jar you downloaded to the `/var/packages/CrashPlan/target/bin` directory